# Wordrpress - Except homepage (index.html) all the pages are blank white screen

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

So I have a WordPress website except for the homepage which is an index.html file everything is coming blank white screen whereas when I just save a post in the draft everything is working in the draft preview. the whole website is made with custom HTML-CSS-Js by some other dev using the basic theme, I migrated the site to a testing server with all-in-one migration. I have used Wp_debug and did not get any error. added the basic htaccess file for troubleshooting. I have also tried disabling all the plugins nothing is getting displayed as when I try to inspect it is showing a blank HTML page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it might be a PHP issue where when you are installing the site locally xampp PHP will not match with the production, which causes many issues. For that only solution is use the older PHP there are many ways you can set up a 2 PHPs version with a single xampp installation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create pages hierarchy like page.php index.php single.php etc if not in the wordpress you must need to create it in order to display pages, posts also you must need to break header.php and footer.php and include it in the templates.

Comment: Yeah all the pages are created as I said the basic theme was used with all the pages